# In AWS or Azure cloud architecture, why would I choose message queues over polling a database?

Tags: database, message-queue, n-tier-architecture

In the past I have used message queues to handle spikes in demand. This system works fine, except for logging purposes. I write successfully processed messages to a database for reporting and logging. This makes me wonder why I don't just write the message into a database from the beginning, and have my "worker roles" poll the database, rather than the message queue.

I'm guessing this is not the best design because as the database grows, polling a huge database just to look for one "unchecked" record to process will become very slow, whereas a message queue just gives me one if I ask for it instantaneously.

Am I missing something? Are there other reasons to choose a message queue over polling a database? I would love to offer users the ability to see what has yet to be processed (floating in the queue) but that operation takes much longer than running a query on the database, so it seems to be a tradeoff.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other reason that springs to mind is blocking/locking.  Typically, if you just poll a database looking for work, it'll work reasonably well as long as you have only one worker digesting the messages.  However, if you want to horizontally scale out, and throw more workers at the problem, you'll typically end up causing lock escalations as you change the work messages in your database based "queue" from "needs to get run" to "ran successfully" or whatever.

Using the message queue takes care of this trickiness for you, as all the thread safety and locking/blocking is out of the way.